# Название файла из пути

Tags: javascript, jquery

Переменная `r` содержит путь `/img/photo/23.02.21/acura_1.jpg`

```
(i = b('<div class="vegas-slide-inner"><a href="'+ r +'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="link_button"><center>MORE THIS CAR >>></center></div></a></div>')
```

Как js правильно вытащить название файла именно `acura` без пути и без последних 6 символов и прописать в данном коде вместо `r`

Полная версия:

```
    !(function (b) {
    "use strict";
    function t(t, s) {
        (this.elmt = t),
            (this.settings = b.extend({}, e, b.vegas.defaults, s)),
            (this.slide = this.settings.slide),
            (this.total = this.settings.slides.length),
            (this.noshow = this.total < 2),
            (this.paused = !this.settings.autoplay || this.noshow),
            (this.ended = !1),
            (this.$elmt = b(t)),
            (this.$timer = null),
            (this.$overlay = null),
            (this.$slide = null),
            (this.timeout = null),
            (this.first = !0),
            (this.transitions = [
                "fade",
                "fade2",
                "blur",
                "blur2",
                "flash",
                "flash2",
                "negative",
                "negative2",
                "burn",
                "burn2",
                "slideLeft",
                "slideLeft2",
                "slideRight",
                "slideRight2",
                "slideUp",
                "slideUp2",
                "slideDown",
                "slideDown2",
                "zoomIn",
                "zoomIn2",
                "zoomOut",
                "zoomOut2",
                "swirlLeft",
                "swirlLeft2",
                "swirlRight",
                "swirlRight2",
            ]),
            (this.animations = ["kenburns", "kenburnsLeft", "kenburnsRight", "kenburnsUp", "kenburnsUpLeft", "kenburnsUpRight", "kenburnsDown", "kenburnsDownLeft", "kenburnsDownRight"]),
            this.settings.transitionRegister instanceof Array || (this.settings.transitionRegister = [this.settings.transitionRegister]),
            this.settings.animationRegister instanceof Array || (this.settings.animationRegister = [this.settings.animationRegister]),
            (this.transitions = this.transitions.concat(this.settings.transitionRegister)),
            (this.animations = this.animations.concat(this.settings.animationRegister)),
            (this.support = { objectFit: "objectFit" in document.body.style, transition: "transition" in document.body.style || "WebkitTransition" in document.body.style, video: b.vegas.isVideoCompatible() }),
            !0 === this.settings.shuffle && this.shuffle(),
            this._init();
    }
    var e = {
            slide: 0,
            delay: 5e3,
            loop: !0,
            preload: !1,
            preloadImage: !1,
            preloadVideo: !1,
            timer: !0,
            overlay: !1,
            autoplay: !0,
            shuffle: !1,
            cover: !0,
            color: null,
            align: "center",
            valign: "center",
            firstTransition: null,
            firstTransitionDuration: null,
            transition: "fade",
            transitionDuration: 1e3,
            transitionRegister: [],
            animation: null,
            animationDuration: "auto",
            animationRegister: [],
            slidesToKeep: 1,
            init: function () {},
            play: function () {},
            pause: function () {},
            walk: function () {},
            slides: [],
        },
        n = {};
    (t.prototype = {
        _init: function () {
            var t,
                s,
                i,
                e,
                n = "BODY" === this.elmt.tagName,
                o = this.settings.timer,
                a = this.settings.overlay,
                r = this;
            this._preload(),
                n ||
                    ((s = b('<div class="vegas-content-scrollable">')),
                    (t = b('<div class="vegas-content">').css("overflow", this.$elmt.css("overflow")).css("padding", this.$elmt.css("padding"))),
                    this.$elmt.css("padding") ||
                        t.css("padding-top", this.$elmt.css("padding-top")).css("padding-bottom", this.$elmt.css("padding-bottom")).css("padding-left", this.$elmt.css("padding-left")).css("padding-right", this.$elmt.css("padding-right")),
                    this.$elmt.css("padding", 0),
                    this.$elmt.clone(!0).children().appendTo(t),
                    (this.elmt.innerHTML = "")),
                o && this.support.transition && ((e = b('<div class="vegas-timer"><div class="vegas-timer-progress">')), (this.$timer = e), this.$elmt.prepend(e)),
                a && ((i = b('<div class="vegas-overlay">')), "string" == typeof a && i.css("background-image", "url(" + a + ")"), (this.$overlay = i), this.$elmt.prepend(i)),
                this.$elmt.addClass("vegas-container"),
                n || (this.$elmt.append(s), s.append(t)),
                setTimeout(function () {
                    r.trigger("init"), r._goto(r.slide), r.settings.autoplay && r.trigger("play");
                }, 1);
        },
        _preload: function () {
            var t;
            for (t = 0; t < this.settings.slides.length; t++)
                (this.settings.preload || this.settings.preloadImages) && this.settings.slides[t].src && (new Image().src = this.settings.slides[t].src),
                    (this.settings.preload || this.settings.preloadVideos) &&
                        this.support.video &&
                        this.settings.slides[t].video &&
                        (this.settings.slides[t].video instanceof Array ? this._video(this.settings.slides[t].video) : this._video(this.settings.slides[t].video.src));
        },
        _random: function (t) {
            return t[Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length)];
        },
        _slideShow: function () {
            var t = this;
            1 < this.total &&
                !this.ended &&
                !this.paused &&
                !this.noshow &&
                (this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    t.next();
                }, this._options("delay")));
        },
        _timer: function (t) {
            var s = this;
            clearTimeout(this.timeout),
                this.$timer &&
                    (this.$timer.removeClass("vegas-timer-running").find("div").css("transition-duration", "0ms"),
                    this.ended ||
                        this.paused ||
                        this.noshow ||
                        (t &&
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                s.$timer
                                    .addClass("vegas-timer-running")
                                    .find("div")
                                    .css("transition-duration", s._options("delay") - 100 + "ms");
                            }, 100)));
        },
        _video: function (t) {
            var s,
                i,
                e = t.toString();
            return n[e]
                ? n[e]
                : (t instanceof Array || (t = [t]),
                  ((s = document.createElement("video")).preload = !0),
                  t.forEach(function (t) {
                      ((i = document.createElement("source")).src = t), s.appendChild(i);
                  }),
                  (n[e] = s));
        },
        _fadeOutSound: function (t, s) {
            var i = this,
                e = s / 10,
                n = t.volume - 0.09;
            0 < n
                ? ((t.volume = n),
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      i._fadeOutSound(t, s);
                  }, e))
                : t.pause();
        },
        _fadeInSound: function (t, s) {
            var i = this,
                e = s / 10,
                n = t.volume + 0.09;
            n < 1 &&
                ((t.volume = n),
                setTimeout(function () {
                    i._fadeInSound(t, s);
                }, e));
        },
        _options: function (t, s) {
            return void 0 === s && (s = this.slide), void 0 !== this.settings.slides[s][t] ? this.settings.slides[s][t] : this.settings[t];
        },
        _goto: function (t) {
            void 0 === this.settings.slides[t] && (t = 0), (this.slide = t);
            var s,
                i,
                e,
                n,
                o,
                a = this.$elmt.children(".vegas-slide"),
                r = this.settings.slides[t].src,
                h = this.settings.slides[t].video,
                d = this._options("delay"),
                l = this._options("align"),
                g = this._options("valign"),
                u = this._options("cover"),
                c = this._options("color") || this.$elmt.css("background-color"),
                p = this,
                m = a.length,
                f = this._options("transition"),
                v = this._options("transitionDuration"),
                y = this._options("animation"),
                _ = this._options("animationDuration");
            function w() {
                p._timer(!0),
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        f &&
                            (p.support.transition
                                ? (a.css("transition", "all " + v + "ms").addClass("vegas-transition-" + f + "-out"),
                                  a.each(function () {
                                      var t = a.find("video").get(0);
                                      t && ((t.volume = 1), p._fadeOutSound(t, v));
                                  }),
                                  s.css("transition", "all " + v + "ms").addClass("vegas-transition-" + f + "-in"))
                                : s.fadeIn(v));
                        for (var t = 0; t < a.length - p.settings.slidesToKeep; t++) a.eq(t).remove();
                        p.trigger("walk"), p._slideShow();
                    }, 100);
            }
            this.settings.firstTransition && this.first && (f = this.settings.firstTransition || f),
                this.settings.firstTransitionDuration && this.first && (v = this.settings.firstTransitionDuration || v),
                this.first && (this.first = !1),
                "repeat" !== u && (!0 === u ? (u = "cover") : !1 === u && (u = "contain")),
                ("random" === f || f instanceof Array) && (f = f instanceof Array ? this._random(f) : this._random(this.transitions)),
                ("random" === y || y instanceof Array) && (y = y instanceof Array ? this._random(y) : this._random(this.animations)),
                ("auto" === v || d < v) && (v = d),
                "auto" === _ && (_ = d),
                (s = b('<div class="vegas-slide"></div>')),
                this.support.transition && f && s.addClass("vegas-transition-" + f),
                this.support.video && h
                    ? (((n = h instanceof Array ? this._video(h) : this._video(h.src)).loop = void 0 === h.loop || h.loop),
                      (n.muted = void 0 === h.mute || h.mute),
                      !1 === n.muted ? ((n.volume = 0), this._fadeInSound(n, v)) : n.pause(),
                      (e = b(n).addClass("vegas-video").css("background-color", c)),
                      this.support.objectFit
                          ? e
                                .css("object-position", l + " " + g)
                                .css("object-fit", u)
                                .css("width", "100%")
                                .css("height", "100%")
                          : "contain" === u && e.css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%"),
                      s.append(e))
                    : ((o = new Image()),
                      (i = b('<div class="vegas-slide-inner"><a href="'console.log(r.replace(/(.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+)/g, ''))'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="link_button"><center>MORE THIS CAR >>></center></div></a></div>')
                          .css("background-image", 'url("' + r + '")')
                          .css("background-color", c)
                          .css("background-position", l + " " + g)),
                      "repeat" === u ? i.css("background-repeat", "repeat") : i.css("background-size", u),
                      this.support.transition && y && i.addClass("vegas-animation-" + y).css("animation-duration", _ + "ms"),
                      s.append(i)),
                this.support.transition || s.css("display", "none"),
                m ? a.eq(m - 1).after(s) : this.$elmt.prepend(s),
                a.css("transition", "all 0ms").each(function () {
                    (this.className = "vegas-slide"), "VIDEO" === this.tagName && (this.className += " vegas-video"), f && ((this.className += " vegas-transition-" + f), (this.className += " vegas-transition-" + f + "-in"));
                }),
                p._timer(!1),
                n ? (4 === n.readyState && (n.currentTime = 0), n.play(), w()) : ((o.src = r), o.complete ? w() : (o.onload = w));
        },
        _end: function () {
            (this.ended = !this.settings.autoplay), this._timer(!1), this.trigger("end");
        },
        shuffle: function () {
            for (var t, s, i = this.total - 1; 0 < i; i--) (s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))), (t = this.settings.slides[i]), (this.settings.slides[i] = this.settings.slides[s]), (this.settings.slides[s] = t);
        },
        play: function () {
            this.paused && ((this.paused = !1), this.next(), this.trigger("play"));
        },
        pause: function () {
            this._timer(!1), (this.paused = !0), this.trigger("pause");
        },
        toggle: function () {
            this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();
        },
        playing: function () {
            return !this.paused && !this.noshow;
        },
        current: function (t) {
            return t ? { slide: this.slide, data: this.settings.slides[this.slide] } : this.slide;
        },
        jump: function (t) {
            t < 0 || t > this.total - 1 || t === this.slide || ((this.slide = t), this._goto(this.slide));
        },
        next: function () {
            if ((this.slide++, this.slide >= this.total)) {
                if (!this.settings.loop) return this._end();
                this.slide = 0;
            }
            this._goto(this.slide);
        },
        previous: function () {
            if ((this.slide--, this.slide < 0)) {
                if (!this.settings.loop) return void this.slide++;
                this.slide = this.total - 1;
            }
            this._goto(this.slide);
        },
        trigger: function (t) {
            var s = [];
            (s = "init" === t ? [this.settings] : [this.slide, this.settings.slides[this.slide]]), this.$elmt.trigger("vegas" + t, s), "function" == typeof this.settings[t] && this.settings[t].apply(this.$elmt, s);
        },
        options: function (t, s) {
            var i = this.settings.slides.slice();
            if ("object" == typeof t) this.settings = b.extend({}, e, b.vegas.defaults, t);
            else {
                if ("string" != typeof t) return this.settings;
                if (void 0 === s) return this.settings[t];
                this.settings[t] = s;
            }
            this.settings.slides !== i && ((this.total = this.settings.slides.length), (this.noshow = this.total < 2), this._preload());
        },
        destroy: function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout),
                this.$elmt.removeClass("vegas-container"),
                this.$elmt.find("> .vegas-slide").remove(),
                this.$elmt.find("> .vegas-wrapper").clone(!0).children().appendTo(this.$elmt),
                this.$elmt.find("> .vegas-wrapper").remove(),
                this.settings.timer && this.$timer.remove(),
                this.settings.overlay && this.$overlay.remove(),
                (this.elmt._vegas = null);
        },
    }),
        (b.fn.vegas = function (s) {
            var i,
                e = arguments,
                n = !1;
            if (void 0 === s || "object" == typeof s)
                return this.each(function () {
                    this._vegas || (this._vegas = new t(this, s));
                });
            if ("string" == typeof s) {
                if (
                    (this.each(function () {
                        var t = this._vegas;
                        if (!t) throw new Error("No Vegas applied to this element.");
                        "function" == typeof t[s] && "_" !== s[0] ? (i = t[s].apply(t, [].slice.call(e, 1))) : (n = !0);
                    }),
                    n)
                )
                    throw new Error('No method "' + s + '" in Vegas.');
                return void 0 !== i ? i : this;
            }
        }),
        (b.vegas = {}),
        (b.vegas.defaults = e),
        (b.vegas.isVideoCompatible = function () {
            return !/(Android|webOS|Phone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        });
})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto || window.m4q);
//# sourceMappingURL=vegas.min.js.map
```

Comment: Часть "более полно" в принципе и не относится к вопросу. Было бы полезно иметь какой-то список возможных вариаций, чтобы понять закономерность. Например, всегда ли после названия следует `_число`, только числа или и что-то другое? Что делать, если слово составное `one_two_3.jpg`

Comment: Да, будут такие названия например: `alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_1.jpg` Поэтому нужно обрезать 6 последних символов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(
  '/img/photo/23.02.21/acura_1.jpg'.replace(/(^.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+$)/g, '')
)
console.log(
  'acura_1.jpg'.replace(/(^.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+$)/g, '')
)
console.log(
  '\\\/\\\/acura_sacura_158.jpg'.replace(/(^.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+$)/g, '')
)
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял:  `(i = b('<div class="vegas-slide-inner"><a href="'console.log('+ r +'.replace(/(.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+)/g, ''))'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="link_button"><center>MORE THIS CAR >>></center></div></a></div>')`

Comment: Результат: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @Serg888 я немного изменил если вы заметили. Не правильно - я дал регулярку, которая обрезает спереди все до слеша включительно и после последнего подчеркивания. Регулярка применяется к строке, т.е. `r.replace(...)`

Comment: @@Serg888 ...разве не видно к чему я ее применяю

Comment: @Serg888 ... и символов надо отрезать не 6, а именно по подчеркиванию, т.к. может быть и такое "acura_sacura_158.jpg"

Comment: `<a href="'console.log(r.replace(/(.*[\\\/]+)|(_[^_]+)/g, ''))'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="link_button"><center>MORE THIS CAR >>></center></div></a>` Результат: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Взгляните на полный скрипт. Может быть что-то не правильно?

Comment: @Serg888 БОЖЕ `console.log` то к чему здесь. Это же просто пример кода чтоб вывести в консоль сайта stackoverflow кликом на [Выполнить код]. Я же даже уже подсказал, замените свой `r` на `r.replace(...)`

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Я убрал `(_[^_]+)` т.к. есть например: `alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_1.jpg` Выводит `alfa` Поэтому выход такой нужно обрезать 6 последних символов. В папке все файлы с окончанием `_1.jpg`

Comment: @Serg888 если в конце ровное кол-во, то можно явно его установить таким выражением `/(^.*[\\\/]+)|(.{6}$)/g`

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно!

Comment: @Serg888 вам не надо ничего убирать, все там нормально выводит, я же пояснил что немного изменил код. Первый вариант у меня был ошибочный. Просто скопируйте заново то что здесь написано. В первом варианте у меня не было символа конца строки `...$)`

Comment: Понял. Спасибо! Скопировал. Все работает.

Comment: Результат можно увидеть здесь: `auto-prodam.com/auto_style/auto_style.php`